# How to get 2 fields from selected material select input?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have a select list that loads a list of companies. Currently I can only get the id or the name of the company.
I need to store the id and name of the selected company in the firestore collection.

Have tried `(selectionChange)="changeCompany($event.value)"`
But this sends an object Object value. How do I the name from this?

```
loadedCompanies: Company[] = [];
```

HTML

```
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select formControlName="companyid" (selectionChange)="changeCompany($event.value)"  placeholder="Select Company" [compareWith]="compareFn">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let lC of loadedCompanies" [value]="lC.id" >
              {{lC.name}}
            </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

changeCompany method

```
    changeCompany(data) {
      this.selectedCompanyName = this.loadedCompanies[data].name;
      console.log('CName' + this.selectedCompanyName);
    }
```

I would like to get the values from the selected object rather than making a second query to firestore to retrieve the company name.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the object Object value? Do you mean this is inside of your console.log? It likely logs like this because you're concatenating it to a string. Try logging with `console.log('Whatever', myValue) to see the contents of what you're attempting to log.
Better yet, use the debugger statement. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp

Comment: Thanks. I used debugger and I get this as the value of data: ```data = {id: "I9ZBt09idvviwbBFHz9r", address: "54 tyrgyt", contactemail: "fg@fdg", contactname: "gdfgfgdf", contactphone: "5435345534", …}```

Comment: If I try data.name I get [object Object]

Comment: Need to see what "name" is on your object

Comment: ```name: "Game"```

Comment: When I try data.name I get undefined

Comment: It'd be easier for me if you updated your question to explain what data you are getting where, or better yet added a StackBlitz minimal reproduction demo of where you are
https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I am subscribing to an observable get the loadedCompanies: ```      this.companyList.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(val);
        this.loadedCompanies = val;
       });```

Comment: This a screenshot of the object in debugger: https://snag.gy/jVhwxE.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, please add a StackBlitz reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this to the following:

```
    changeCompany(data) {
  const inspect = obj => {
    for (const prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        console.log(`${prop}: ${obj[prop]}`);
        if (prop === 'name') {
          this.selectedCompanyName = obj[prop];
        }
        if (prop === 'field1') {
          this.selectedField1 = obj[prop];
        }
        if (prop === 'field2') {
          this.selectedField2 = obj[prop];
        }
      }
    }
  };
  inspect(data);
}
```